# Python - Trying to transfer data between nested lists (IndexError: list assignment index out of range)

Tags: python, list, range, out, index-error

I am aware of what it means to be out of range when indexing, but I am struggling to see why my code is generating this error...

```
import random


howMany = random.randint(1,3)
oldList = [['a',1,2,3], ['b',1,2,3], ['c',1,2,3], ['d',1,2,3], ['e',1,2,3], ['f',1,2,3], ['g',1,2,3], ['h',1,2,3], ['i',1,2,3]]
newList = []
for i in range(0, howMany): 
    newList[i] = oldList[random.randint(0, len(oldList)-1)] # subtract one
```

Comment: are a, b, c, etc. strings or variables? If the latter they need to be defined as well, otherwise this code fails on a different error. Also not all the nested lists are separated with a comma.

Comment: They are strings. I'll edit to the code to make that more clear.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but look into using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because newList is empty (its length is 0). You are trying to access elements in it using an index, but there are no indices. Here's a simpler example of what's happening:

```
>>> newList = []
>>> i = 0
>>> newList[i] = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What you want to do is use `append()`:

```
import random


howMany = random.randint(1,3)
oldList = [['a',1,2,3], ['b',1,2,3], ['c',1,2,3], ['d',1,2,3], ['e',1,2,3], ['f',1,2,3], ['g',1,2,3], ['h',1,2,3], ['i',1,2,3]]
newList = []
for i in range(0,howMany): 
    newList.append(oldList[random.randint(0, len(oldList)-1)]) # subtract one
```